# How can I further format the response I get from a standard HTML checklist?

Tags: html, checkbox

I hope you are good!

I built this piece of code, which results in the following design of a checklist, in which I am able to select multiple items from a list -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Show Checkboxes</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" id="item1" name="item1" value="Tshirt">
  <label for="item1"> Tshirt</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="item2" name="item2" value="Jeans">
  <label for="item2"> Jeans</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="item3" name="item3" value="Shirt">
  <label for="item3"> Shirt</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="item4" name="item4" value="Trousers">
  <label for="item4"> Trousers</label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The checklist I get :

[image: my checklist]

And when I choose some items and click submit [for this time I chose Jeans & Trousers], I get my response in this format : **`item2=Jeans&item4=Trousers`**. Unfortunately, I cannot further work with this kind of response format...

The format I need should be more like : **`Jeans , Trousers`**. No item-ids, and no = signs - just their display names... Is it possible to get a response like that?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

**Edit** : Here's the code I took inspiration from - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_checkbox

Comment: You could use `method="post"`, name all the inputs as an array by calling them all `item[]`, and them `implode()` the array when it arrives in your PHP code. But it'll need to have a variable name so that you can reference it in the code.

Comment: use item[] instead item1 , item2 , item3 only item[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of values in your backed using name format like `myarrayName[]`. The `name` attribute doesn't have to be unique. For example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" id="item1" name="item[]" value="Tshirt">
  <label for="item1"> Tshirt</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="item2" name="item[]" value="Jeans">
  <label for="item2"> Jeans</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="item3" name="item[]" value="Shirt">
  <label for="item3"> Shirt</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="item4" name="item[]" value="Trousers">
  <label for="item4"> Trousers</label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```